# What kind of curtain rod should I use to maximize light blocking on a sliding glass door?

Tags: sliding-glass-door, curtain-rail

1. I'm super light sensitive, I basically wake up half an hour after sunrise
2. This presents a problem when the sun rises at 5AM and I go to bed at midnight
3. No, a sleep mask isn't a great option. I'd prefer not to go into it. Yes, I've tried it.

The bedroom has a sliding glass door that is 76x82 inches and faces east. I bought a panel blind that said it as 99.99% light blocking. It's not. I need to replace it with something that is easy to open but actually blocks that morning sun. Any curtain rod that I've found sits about 2 inches off the wall, which means there is 1.5-1.75 inches of sun coming through on the sides. Enough to wake me up. Right now I have blackout curtains that are hanging off of nails. Not aesthetically pleasing and not easy to open -- but they definitely work because they sit right on the molding.

The molding around the the door is about 3/8".

Not interested in anything that is outside the house (on the other side of the door). Don't want to go outside to allow the sun into my room.

What's my best option for a curtain rod that will sit close enough to the window to actually block the light well but also be fairly easy to open?

Comment: You might want to look at window/door valances instead.  They fit above the window/curtain rod and hang down over the curtains/window shades.

Comment: They seem not wide enough when I look online

Comment: Add sliding door to your search.  Might need/want a second rod just above the curtain so the valance is tight to the wall and drapes over the curtain like a box/L shape.

Comment: My rec would be to basically build a box over the curtain rod above the door, to block the light that comes in from there.  Line the interior with black fabric to minimize any internal reflectivity.  If you get light bypass along the sides too, you could also box those out in a similar fashion.

Comment: @Huesmann see the answer below, looks like the Vikings have already solved this problem

Answer (score 1):

A leather strap curtain holder will probably do the trick. It holds the curtain right against the wall.

This issue is common in Scandinavia, where they have no nights during mid-summer. You can look into suppliers that serve those countries, eg IKEA.

Comment: Good idea, I'll check it out.